# Pythagorean Quadruple Parametric Equation in 3 variables

Tags: parametric

I am looking for a pythagorean quadruple generator in 3 variables. I know this one with 4 variables.

$$a=2mp+2nq \\
b=2np-2mq \\
c=p^2+q^2-(n^2+m^2) \\
d=p^2+q^2+n^2+m^2 $$

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a=2mp
b=2np
c=p^2-(m^2+n^2)
d=p^2+m^2+n^2

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanQuadruple.html

Comment: you ought to do a simple test on computer, this three parameter method is very far from giving all quadruples. To be specific, it misses $(2,3,6,7)$